# What can I deduce next about this daily Light Up (Akari) puzzle? (Feb. 22, 2024, 7x7 Hard)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

So yesterday, I was searching for online logical deduction puzzles when I came across this website called [Brain Bashers](https://www.brainbashers.com/puzzles.asp) which is a site filled with many different types of puzzles.

I have been going through each of the puzzle types and solving all of the different board types for each day including the weekly challenge.

I found this morning that they had Light Up puzzles, and have so far beaten 5 of the puzzles, and am currently stuck on the 7x7 Hard puzzle. Here is my progress so far:

[image]

I am pretty sure that there is not a bulb at R3C3 because since it is still required that I have one more bulb right next to the 3. This in turn would lead to a contradiction because bulbs cannot light other bulbs up. So really this is my progress so far:

[image]

However, my question is, is there anything else I could deduce from here? I have never really been that into Light Up puzzles in the past, so I might be missing something that could be easily deduced right now.

---

Some info about Light Up/Akari:

> Light Up (Japanese: 美術館 *bijutsukan*, art gallery) which is also known as Akari (明かり *akari*, light) is a logic puzzle published by [Nikoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikoli_(publisher)) in which players must place bulbs on a black and white rectangular grid such that no two bulbs shine light on each other.
>
> A number on a square tells you how many bulbs surround the square **orthogonally**.
>
> The goal is to eventually fill up the grid with light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - There has to be a bulb at R2C3, as one of the orthogonals to the 3 has a bulb, and if it is R3C4 then R2C3 can't be lit.
> - There is an obvious bulb bottom right as thats the only way to light up the corner
>  - There must be a bulb in C4 in R6 or R7 to light further up C4. It can only be placed in one of these to avoid contradiction with the 2. You can quickly deduce the final grid from here, and I'll leave that for you to do